Moral hazard, prosecution and fines
I wonder whether there are theoretical or empirical papers on the pros and cons of giving back part of the fines paid by someone to cover a part of the costs endured by the prosecuting body.
I have in mind a financial supervisor and thinks it is to some extent the case of the SEC.
The intuition is that there might be a middle ground between affecting all the fines which would incentivize too much condemnations and not giving anything back which might desintivize doing the extra mile
